# How to use regular expressions do reverse search?

Tags: python, regex, search, reverse

For example:
My string is: `123456789  nn  nn  oo nn  nn mlm nn203`.
My target is: `nn`.

Then, I match string from the end to the beginning and return the first match result and its postion.
In this examlpe, the result is `nn` start in [-5] end in [-3].
I wrote the simple funcitonto  do this process, but how to use regular expressions to do this job?

Comment: Hm, if the search term was 'na', would you like it to match forward or reverse in the string (ie match man or name)?

Answer (score 21):

For the string itself, just do a findall and use the last one:

```
import re

st='123456 nn1 nn2 nn3 nn4 mlm nn5 mlm'
 
print(re.findall(r'(nn\d+)',st)[-1])
```

Prints `nn5`

You can also do the same thing using `finditer` which makes it easier finding the relevant indexes:

```
print([(m.group(),m.start(),m.end()) for m in re.finditer(r'(nn\d+)',st)][-1])
```

Prints `('nn5', 27, 30)`

---

If you have a lot of matches and you only want the last, sometimes it makes sense to simply reverse the string and pattern:

```
m=re.search(r'(\d+nn)',st[::-1])
offset=m.start(1)
print(st[-m.start(1)-len(m.group(1)):-m.start(1)])
```

Or, modify your pattern into something that only the last match could possible satisfy:

```
# since fixed width, you can use a lookbehind:
m=re.search(r'(...(?<=nn\d)(?!.*nn\d))',st)
if m: print(m.group(1))
```

Or, take advantage of the greediness of `.*` which will always return the last of multiple matches:

```
# .* will skip to the last match of nn\d
m=re.search(r'.*(nn\d)', st)
if m: print(m.group(1))
```

Any of those prints `nn5`

Comment: Here's something similar to your code that many might consider more readable: http://pastebin.com/J7SsXjsS (Note that `search` does exist after the loop is finished.)

Comment: In that link I gave, you'll get an error if you don't get any results, though (so be sure to handle it).

Comment: reversing the string was the idea I needed

Answer (score 7):

First, if you're not looking for a regular expression, `string.rfind` is a lot easier to get right.

You can use a regular expression by using a negative lookahead, see the documentation of [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
import re
s = "123456789 nn nn oo nn nn mlm nn203"
match = re.search("(nn)(?!.*nn.*)", s)

# for your negative numbers:
print (match.start()-len(s), match.end()-len(s))
# (-5, -3)
```

Comment: I'd recommend the use of re.DOTALL flag here, as . (dot character), by default, doesn't include newline characters.

Answer (score 4):

Idea:

- find reversed regexp (in your case irrelevant) in reversed string
- resulting indexes convert to negative numbers + switch start<->end

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "123456789 nn nn oo nn nn mlm nn203"
>>> m = re.search("(nn)", s[::-1])
>>> -m.end(), -m.start()
(-5, -3)
```