# Regex right-to-left parsing in Python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to parse regex from right to left in python?

I have a few huge regexes that take about a second to run on my input, for a total run-time of a few minutes. So I tried to test the performance of my regexes, and [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) had an option to parse regex from right to left, which resulted in about a million times faster execution because of quicker failing.

Comment: Not sure but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510017/how-to-use-regular-expressions-do-reverse-search

Comment: nope, there's nothing about that in `re` or `regex` modules.

Comment: .net supports it, so it's doable http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-19

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the way is to reverse the string (and to write the pattern according to the new string):

string:

```
'John likes to eat mushrooms'[::-1]
```

pattern (what like John?):

```
r'^(.+) sekil nohJ$'
```

---

You can also change the re module to the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that provides a reverse search flag `(?r)`:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'(?r)\w+(?=\W+\w*e)', 'John likes to eat mushrooms')
['to', 'John']
```

*(Take care of this feature, as .net RightToLeft option, results may be counter-intuitive.)*

Comment: So I have to rewrite all my regexes? Doesn't really sound that great.

Comment: @mbomb007: no you can't do that. `$John likes )+.(^`

Comment: Right, I always forget about the parentheses.

Comment: Why, python regex has not right to left search? It effects the performance.

Comment: @keramat: AFAIK, only this module and the .net languages regular expressions have this feature.